# extjs : how can I hide series name from legend?

Tags: javascript, extjs, charts

I want to hide a series name from legend, how can I do it ?

```
Ext.each(chart.series.items, function(series) {
            if (series.yField = 'done') {
                alert('found done');
                // hides the series
                series.hideAll();

                series.showInLegend = false; // STILL SHOWS
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In the Ext js 6.2 have the option "showInLegend" within the series. :)

Comment: It's unclear how this answers the question at hand. Can you expand on this to tell us what steps to take to resolve the problem described in the question?

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround you can do to specifically target certain legend entries, e.g. if you specify a template for the legend:

```
legend: {
    itemTpl: [
        '<tpl if="value != seriesToHide">', // <= template condition
            '<span class="{[values.disabled?\'x-legend-inactive\':\'\']}" style="background:{mark};"></span>{name}',
        '</tpl>'
    ]
}
```

You can use the template condition to show/hide certain entries depending on the passed value (if this doesnt work, replace value with name).

Alternatively, you can also assign the template a class, e.g. `x-legend-series-{name}` and in your CSS file, create classes following that pattern for those series you wish to hide, e.g.

```
.x-legend-series-seriesToHide{
  display:none;
}
```

e.g.

```
legend: {
    itemTpl: [
        '<tpl>',
           '<span class="x-legend-series-{name}">',
              '<span class="{[values.disabled?\'x-legend-inactive\':\'\']}" style="background:{mark};"></span>{name}',
           '</span>'
        '</tpl>'
    ]
}
```

Comment: so the `showInLegend` property is no use in Extjs?? How can I do this via the controller?

Comment: Its implementation is spotty, you should make sure that on the chart object itself, you specify the legend property as an object, within which you specify a position. showInLegend will then work, but not for all chart types. E.g. on the chart object, add: legend:{position:'top'}}

Comment: Yes I have the position in the legend object, but still showInLegend doesn't work. I think I'll go by your solution, but how can I assign the `name` parameter dynamically via the controller? can I put the names in an array and loop in the template? Because I have many names I need to hide...